# Symfony 3 populate anonymous token sometimes

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, fosrestbundle

Don't know why it doing that but sometimes it seems Symfony 3 losing my current user, depending on which route I'm calling.

```
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] request.INFO: Matched route "webapi_get_payment_method". {"route":"webapi_get_payment_method","route_parameters":{"_controller":"MYPROJECT\\CoreBundle\\Controller\\CorePaymentsRestController::getPaymentMethodAction","_format":"json","_route":"webapi_get_payment_method"},"request_uri":"http://localhost/v1/webapi/billing/paymentmethod","method":"GET"} []
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] request.INFO: Matched route "webapi_get_playlist_list". {"route":"webapi_get_playlist_list","route_parameters":{"_controller":"MYPROJECT\\CoreBundle\\Controller\\CorePlaylistRestController::getPlaylistListAction","_format":"json","platformSrc":"MYPROJECT","_route":"webapi_get_playlist_list"},"request_uri":"http://localhost/v1/webapi/playlist/list/MYPROJECT","method":"GET"} []
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] request.INFO: Matched route "webapi_invoices_history". {"route":"webapi_invoices_history","route_parameters":{"_controller":"MYPROJECT\\CoreBundle\\Controller\\CorePaymentsRestController::invoicesHistoryAction","_format":"json","_route":"webapi_invoices_history"},"request_uri":"http://localhost/v1/webapi/billing/history","method":"GET"} []
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] request.INFO: Matched route "webapi_overview". {"route":"webapi_overview","route_parameters":{"_controller":"MYPROJECT\\CoreBundle\\Controller\\CorePaymentsRestController::overviewAction","_format":"json","_route":"webapi_overview"},"request_uri":"http://localhost/v1/webapi/billing/overview","method":"GET"} []
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] security.DEBUG: Read existing security token from the session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] doctrine.DEBUG: SQL SELECT ...
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] security.DEBUG: User was reloaded from a user provider. {"username":"Thomas","provider":"FOS\\UserBundle\\Security\\EmailUserProvider"} []
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] security.INFO: No expression found; abstaining from voting. [] []
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\DebugHandlersListener::configure"} []
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ValidateRequestListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\ValidateRequestListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\EventListener\\SessionListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\RouterListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "MYPROJECT\MainBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"MYPROJECT\\MainBundle\\EventListener\\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "FOS\RestBundle\EventListener\BodyListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"FOS\\RestBundle\\EventListener\\BodyListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Firewall::onKernelRequest"} []
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "MYPROJECT\MainBundle\EventListener\MaintenanceListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"MYPROJECT\\MainBundle\\EventListener\\MaintenanceListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "MYPROJECT\MainBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"MYPROJECT\\MainBundle\\EventListener\\SessionListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] event.DEBUG: Notified event "security.authentication.success" to listener "MYPROJECT\UserBundle\Listener\SecuritySuccessListener::handle". {"event":"security.authentication.success","listener":"MYPROJECT\\UserBundle\\Listener\\SecuritySuccessListener::handle"} []
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] security.INFO: No expression found; abstaining from voting. [] []
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] security.DEBUG: Access denied, the user is not fully authenticated; redirecting to authentication entry point. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AccessDeniedException(code: 403): Access Denied. at E:\\Logiciels\\wamp64\\www\\MYPROJECT-2.5\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Firewall\\AccessListener.php:70)"} []
[2016-11-19 17:35:26] security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry point. [] []
```

Pretty strange, never had this error before.
I use FOSUserBundle/HWIOAuth/REST on a Symfony 3.1.6 , PHP7.0.10
Any ideas ?

**EDIT** Clear cookies in my browser solved the issue...

Comment: pst can you provide more information? like configuration firewalls in security section